# Really removing CVS files from a module

Tags: cvs

Someone in my development team committed a huge intermediate file into our CVS repository (run as Client-Server configuration where I have no server-side access).

I have "cvs removed" the file, but the existence of this file seriously slows down working with that module.

The file was never needed, if I request that the FILENAME.EXT,v is deleted (e.g. the comma-V file on the server), would that be enough to wipe all existence of the file from the module?

I'm looking for a simple solution ideally not running the CVS tool as our IT department are unable to use it (and complex requests frequently get ignored).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you request that file.txt,v is deleted from the filesystem, you should be ok - clients operating in that module may get strange errors if they didn't run 'cvs update' since the file was cvs rm'd.

Either have your users remove the module and check out the module again or get them to edit CVS/Entries and remove any mention of the file in question.